# Is there any Apis to displayed the iWork files in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, iwork

I want to display some iWork file in iphone? Is there any apis to help to display it?

Answer (score 0):

The quick look panels are capable of presenting iWork files, as is Safari. Take a look at [UIDocumentInteractionController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009304-CH1-SW5) to see how.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Technical Q&A QA1630 Using UIWebView to display select document types (deals with iWork,Office and rtf document types). Sample of the code is provided there.
When you try it, it works on the device, does not work on the simulator.
(I tested it with SDK 5; worked on the device, reported  run time error on the simulator).
Hynek