# How to load .pages (iWork) in UIWebview?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiwebview, iwork

I want to load a local file, example.pages in UIWebview. I tried with this

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"example" ofType:@"pages" inDirectory:@""];
NSUrl *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webview loadRequest:request];
```

but doesn't work. 
Anyone?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A Pages document is not HTML. You cannot load it in a UIWebView.

Comment: so how to load .pages documents?

Comment: I take that back; it may be possible. See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543295/is-there-any-apis-to-displayed-the-iwork-files-in-iphone) and [QA 1630](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1630/_index.html).

Comment: I tried with loading the document as a zip file, example.pages.zip 

but still doesn't work.
(Keynote, Numbers and Pages documents must be created with iWork '06 or iWork '08. iWork '06 and iWork '08 documents are document packages and must be ZIP compressed for UIWebView to recognize them. You must retain both extensions in the file name, such as presentation.key.zip, spreadsheet.numbers.zip or paper.pages.zip.)